# Detect network connection 2g,3g,4g,wifi using php

Tags: php, wifi, network-connection

My web application having feature for live audio streaming.i would like to know if there is any way to detect the network(`2G`, `3G`, `4G` or `wifi`) on which user has accessing the web on their devices.

I've searched high and low but unable to find any scripts or instructions on how to get user network `2G`,`3G`,`4G` or `wifi`.

Comment: You can sometimes tell the difference between WIFI and non-WIFI, and sometimes you can't tell any difference.

You can never tell the difference between 2G/3G/4G/ with php.

Comment: As far as I know, you can use a clientside script to run a download speed check which will advise you how fast the client can download from you. Streaming sites usually have some sort of detection like this, like YouTube. That's about as good as you'll get at the moment.

Comment: @Sippy, Thanks. can you please tell me that clientside script ?

Comment: I've never made one. Do some trial and error, see if you can learn yourself. If you can't, post your attempts here and people will help you out if they can.

Comment: @Daan, there is any 3rd party api through which i can find user network connection(2G,3G,4G or wifi)..??